# Forecast with ARIMA model using specific months and years in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, forecast, model-fitting

I want to train my model using specific years and months (which are not a continuous sequence). Then use the fitted model coefficient along with data from `July 10 to August 31` of the `year 2017` to forecast `Yr20`  `July 10 to August 31` `Flow` data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tseries)
library(forecast)

set.seed(1500)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), to = as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "day"),
                            Flow = runif(3287,25,75)) %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date), JDay = yday(Date)) %>% 
  filter(Year %in% c(2011,2012,2015,2017)) %>% 
  filter(between(Month, 7,8))

Yr20 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-07-09"), by = "day"),
                  Flow = runif(191,20,60))

# acf(DF$Flow)
AA <- auto.arima(DF$Flow) # this will gave me order of the model
fitModel <- arima(DF$Flow, order = c(1,1,1)) # fit the model
#Forecast_flow <- forecast(fitModel, h = 10) # just a rough example using forecast function
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find it much easier to use the fable package rather than the forecast package for this, not least because it handles daily data much better. Here is some code that I *think* does what you want.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(tsibble)
library(fable)

# Generate artificial data and create a tsibble object
set.seed(1500)
DF <- tibble(
    Date = seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"),
               to = as.Date("2020-07-09"),
               by = "day"),
    Flow = runif(length(Date), 25, 75)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Year = year(Date),
    Month = month(Date),
  ) %>%
  as_tsibble(index=Date)
DF
#> # A tsibble: 3,843 x 4 [1D]
#>    Date        Flow  Year Month
#>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2010-01-01  56.2  2010     1
#>  2 2010-01-02  73.6  2010     1
#>  3 2010-01-03  58.0  2010     1
#>  4 2010-01-04  42.1  2010     1
#>  5 2010-01-05  40.5  2010     1
#>  6 2010-01-06  37.9  2010     1
#>  7 2010-01-07  44.8  2010     1
#>  8 2010-01-08  73.1  2010     1
#>  9 2010-01-09  72.5  2010     1
#> 10 2010-01-10  65.7  2010     1
#> # … with 3,833 more rows
```

```r
# Fit model to July/August from 2011, 2012, 2015, 2017
modelFit <- DF %>% filter(
    Year %in% c(2011, 2012, 2015, 2017),
    between(Month, 7, 8)
  ) %>%
  # Add NAs to fill in the missing observations
  fill_gaps() %>%
  # Estimate non-seasonal ARIMA model
  model(
    ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0,0,0))
  )
modelFit
#> # A mable: 1 x 1
#>   `ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0))`
#>                        <model>
#> 1       <ARIMA(1,0,0) w/ mean>
```

```r
modelFit %>%
  # Apply to all data up to 9 July 2020 without re-estimating parameters
  refit(new_data = DF) %>%
  # Forecast to end of August 2020
  forecast(
    new_data=tsibble(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-07-10"),
                        to = as.Date("2020-08-31"),
                        by = "day"),
                     index=Date)
  )
#> # A fable: 53 x 4 [1D]
#> # Key:     .model [1]
#>    .model                     Date             Flow .mean
#>    <chr>                      <date>         <dist> <dbl>
#>  1 ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0)) 2020-07-10 N(49, 208)  49.4
#>  2 ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0)) 2020-07-11 N(50, 208)  49.6
#>  3 ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0)) 2020-07-12 N(50, 208)  49.6
#>  4 ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0)) 2020-07-13 N(50, 208)  49.6
#>  5 ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0)) 2020-07-14 N(50, 208)  49.6
#>  6 ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0)) 2020-07-15 N(50, 208)  49.6
#>  7 ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0)) 2020-07-16 N(50, 208)  49.6
#>  8 ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0)) 2020-07-17 N(50, 208)  49.6
#>  9 ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0)) 2020-07-18 N(50, 208)  49.6
#> 10 ARIMA(Flow ~ PDQ(0, 0, 0)) 2020-07-19 N(50, 208)  49.6
#> # … with 43 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Rob- Can i feed the July 07 - Aug 31 data of the `year 2017` into `modelFit`? What it means that we are assuming that the 2017 (July-august) conditions will repeat itself in the `Year 2020`. How i can extract the `Flow` and `Date` from `modelFit` forecast?